# How to load a texture in three.js / javascript without interrupting main thread?

Tags: javascript, three.js

In a project of mine I need to load some pretty large textures and map them onto spheres. They are generally acceptable in their loading time with the exception of a few large ones. These large textures take up to ten seconds to load and during this time the entire app freezes. I'd like to somehow do all the loading in the background and then once and only once the textures are downloaded, map them onto my spheres.

I have tried using callback function and promises, even the built in [.loadAsync](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/loaders/Loader.loadAsync) of the texture loader but it never changed the duration of the freeze.

If someone knows how to load without this problem it would be of great use. My project can be found [here](https://sd79.bc.ca/solar_system_sim/planetesimal.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid the texture decode overhead when texture is uploaded to the GPU, you have two options:

- Use [ImageBitmapLoader](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=imageb#api/en/loaders/ImageBitmapLoader) in your app instead of `TextureLoader`. The documentation page provides a code example that shows how you use the loader. There is also a link to a complete example. The underlying `ImageBitmap` API provides an asynchronous and resource efficient way to use textures in WebGL. Keep in mind that this API is not supported in all browsers.
- Consider to use a compressed texture format like [Basis](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=basis#examples/en/loaders/BasisTextureLoader) which will also have positive impact on video memory consumption. However, the related workflow is more complicated than the first option.

Comment: How can i make basis work asynchronously? If you can't, which is better? Asynchronous imagebitmap or just plain basis?

Comment: I suggest you start with `ImageBitmapLoader`. If the performance is not good enough, try it with Basis.

Comment: I am going to try both. Is there a way to use the basis converter on windows? It seems to be linux exclusive.